# High CPU usage with unknown cause

Tags: cpu, troubleshooting

I'm having issues with my intel i5 6600k @ 4.5 GHz. I've tried undoing the OC and I've even tried underclocking, yet the issue persists. I could use some help troubleshooting. Temperatures lie around 25 c idle and 55-60 c under load. Most actions feel choppy, as you can see in the gif under.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/wtgxjG2.gifv]

Specifications:

[image]

[image: http://imgur.com/a/HvLA8]

[image]

Intel i5 6600k @ 4.5 GHz
4x4 GB 2400 MHz CAS 9
Gigabyte G1 GTX970
Corsair RM750
Asus z170-a

Update 1: 
CPU usage spikes from 2% to 45 % just from moving mouse in circles. Maybe it's related to USB Controller?

Comment: I just want to get some silly questions out of the way. Is your GPU driver properly installed and functioning? Is your monitor plugged into your GPU and not your onboard video? When did this start, after the overclock? How did it act when you first put it together? Have you run a full MemTest on your RAM? Can you reset the BIOS to defaults by removing the CMOS battery and see if the issue persists? Are all of your motherboard drivers properly installed? <- By this I mean do you see any yellow exclamation marks in your device manager? Why do you suspect the USB controller?

Comment: Had the latest drivers, used DDU to clean and installed 362.00, no luck. Monitors are plugged into the graphics card. It was functioning normal when I first put the system together, and it was working properly with the OC until about a week ago. I haven't done a memtest yet, I don't have a optical drive nor USB. I tried creating a bootable local disk with memtest on, but I couldn't get it to work. All motherboard drivers should be properly installed, there's nothing in device manager suggesting otherwise. I ran performance report, it said I had a high average interrupts /processor.

Comment: Check out http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f217/performance-monitor-says-high-interrupts-per-processor-591240.html

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select "First Level", under  Resource select **CPU usage** and click on **start**. Now repeat the action that triggers the CPU usage. After you did this click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file (+ NGENPDB folder) into 1 zip, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here. I'll analyze it and look what causes it

Comment: have you captured the trace of the CPU usage?

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't responded. I haven't had access to my computer for some time since I've been away. I'll try and do it when I get back.